# Redshift: Cannot use aggregate function inside UDF's?

Tags: amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions

I have written the below code:

```
create or replace function max_price() 
    returns real 
    volatile
as 
$$
    select 
        max(main_amount)
    from
        table
$$ 
language sql;
```

I am receiving this error message:
ERROR:  The select expression can not have aggregate or window function.
CONTEXT:  Create SQL function "max_price" body

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 1):

No, Redshift UDFs are scalar - each "row" of input values returns one output.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-creating-a-scalar-sql-udf.html

You may be able to use a Stored Procedure to obtain the result you are looking for.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-create.html

Answer (score 1):

A scalar User-Defined Function in Amazon Redshift cannot issue a `SELECT` command that retrieves data from a table. It is intended as a means of calculating a number, rather than querying the database.

From [Creating a scalar SQL UDF - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-creating-a-scalar-sql-udf.html):

> The SELECT clause can't include any of the following types of clauses: FROM, INTO, WHERE, GROUP BY, ORDER BY, LIMIT

If you need to consult another table as part of the function, use a [Stored procedure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-overview.html).